# ckeditor and cakephp - I can't make the text area bigger - what am I doing wrong

Tags: php, javascript, css, cakephp, ckeditor

sorry for being such a plonker but I'm a bit new and this is doing my 'ed in.

I'm using cakephp and I've got a form which uses ckeditor as the textarea. I include the javascript file and jquery and then simply put:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Campaign.story',array('rows'=>'5', 'cols'=>'15','class'=>'ckeditor'));
```

in a view file to call the editor. This causes the ckeditor to appear ok but I can't get it to the size I want it. No matter what I change the above to I can't get it to be the proper size. As soon as I remove the class it sizes properly.

The above makes this:

```
<div class="input textarea">
    <label for="CampaignStory">Story</label>
    <textarea name="data[Campaign][story]" rows="5" cols="15" class="ckeditor" id="CampaignStory" ></textarea>
</div>
```

I've tried using css to make it wider like this:

```
#CampaignStory{width:400px;}
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I think we need to see the ckeditor code that attaches the editor. Have you looked at the ckeditor docs for a width option?

Comment: Hi there, heres the link to the configuration bit of the editor http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations There seems to be loads of options but I can't spot anything to do with size

Comment: It's right at the bottom [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html). It' just `width`. I can't show you how to use it as you haven't posted the ckeditor init code.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this :) I'm not sure what you mean about the init code. I followed this (short) tutorial http://amilan.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/ckeditor-integration-in-cakephp/ to install it.

Comment: Is this maybe what you're talking about as init code? http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar I've been staring at this and the link you posted trying to figure out what to do but I'm none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
config.width = '1000px';  // or whatever
```

in /ckeditor/config.js

The editor area replaces the textarea. Changing cols / rows of the underlying textarea won't change ckEditors interface.

will

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify width and hieght in your input and expect work fine with CKEDITOR.Beacause 
it wont adjust height and width of CKEDitor

> To specify height and width of of a CKEDiTOR

field use this code in your css

```
.cke_contents{
height: 400px !important;
width: 550px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to CKEditor configuration file in your application, and look for width property and change the default value of your choice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14577070)

Comment: Why? What's the problem with my question?